# resolve function not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJs. I tried creating a very simple sample for understanding Promise.
Please see the below code:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3221/

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div ng-controller="displayController">
          <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Learn Promise" ng-click="Click()" />
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('displayController', function ($scope, $q) {
        alert('Ctrl');
        $scope.Click = function () {
            alert('1');
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promisse= deferred.promise;
            promisse.then(function (successResult) {
                alert('Inside Promise success ' + successResult);
            }, function (failureResult) {
                alert('Inside Promise Failure ' + failureResult);
            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                alert('2');
                deferred.resolve('After timeout');
                alert('3');
            }, 1000);

        }
    });
```

After the timeout limit of 1000, I am able to see alert('2') and alert('3') but none of the alert's inside the promisse.then() fire.
Why is this so?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this but could it be that you need to call `deferred.promise` as a function with parentheses? `deferred.promise()`. If not, just ignore me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:
You're using javascript's setTimeout. I'd recomment using `$timeout` which is provided by angular. (If you really want to use setTimeout, you'd have to do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){ deferred.resolve('resolving value'); });
}, 1000);
```

This is because setTimeout is outside of angular and it doesn't know that the promise should be resolved (because the $digest cycle doesn't see that it has been changed)

Also, you cannot reject a promise which has been resolved (or vice versa). A promise can only be resolved or rejected just once. If you want to reject a promise after resolving, you have to create a new promise object.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hK9XW/2/

I have used $timeout instead of setTimeout here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your call to `resolve` inside `$rootScope.$apply()` as the `setTimeout` function is not covered inside Angular.JS digest cycle. But in your case, a better solution would be to simply use the `$timeout` service which is guaranteed run inside angular.js digest cycle:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('displayController', function ($scope, $q, $timeout) {
        alert('Ctrl');
        $scope.Click = function () {
            alert('1');
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promisse= deferred.promise;
            promisse.then(function (successResult) {
                alert('Inside Promise success ' + successResult);
            }, function (failureResult) {
                alert('Inside Promise Failure ' + failureResult);
            });

            $timeout(function () {
                alert('2');
                deferred.resolve('After timeout');
                alert('3');
            }, 1000);

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!